# d3.js partition.nodes(root) does not set the nodes x or dx values

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, d3.js

I am trying to create an icicle tree using d3.js using data from a .json file. The issue I have is that the x and dx attributes of the partitions nodes are always set to 0. I would expect that the x and dx values would be set depending on the number of nodes at the same depth. eg. in the example below Women and Men would have a dx of .5 their children would have a dx of 0.25 I probably am making an incorrect assumption because this is a new topic for me. I would appreciate any insight on why these values are always 0 or how I can have the values set the way I would expect.

The contents of the data.json file is:

```
{
 "name": "Segment",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "women",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "recency: >3months", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "recency: between 3 and 6months", "size": 3812}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "men",
     "children": [
      {"name": "recency: >3months", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "recency: between 3 and 6months", "size": 5731}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I am using the following code to set the data for a d3.layout.partition():

```
var partition = d3.layout.partition()
 //   .children(function(d) { return isNaN(d.value) ? d3.entries(d.value) : null; })
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var rect = svg.selectAll("rect");

d3.json("data.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;
  rect = rect
      .data(partition.nodes(root))
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.dx); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.dy); })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value); })//d.children ? d : d.parent).key()
      .on("click", clicked);
});

function clicked(d) {
  x.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
  y.domain([d.y, 1]).range([d.y ? 20 : 0, height]);
```

Answer (score 0):

*DoH* I figured it out. I changed the word size in my json file to value and the x and dx values are now being set.